# How to display average values from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that holds details on various video games and user accounts. A user is able to review a game and the score is put into a review table.
I am trying to retrieve the average score for each game and have it displayed on a webpage. My SQL statement within PHP looks like this

```
$sqlOverall = "SELECT CAST(AVG('scoreOverall') AS DECIMAL('10,1')) 
               FROM 'ratings' 
               WHERE gameID = '$id'";
$scoreOverall = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOverall);
```

But when I try to echo $scoreOverall it returns blank.

Comment: Wrap off `quotes` from tables name instead use `backtick`

Answer (score 0):

try this below query

```
$selquery="SELECT CAST(AVG(scoreOverall) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) FROM ratings WHERE gameID='$id'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $selquery);
```

Comment: Returns error    
    "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"
When i try to echo $scoreOverall

Comment: The $result variable holds an object (of type mysqli_result), from which you can fetch the scoreOverall you need to output.
echo $result->fetch_object()->scoreOverall;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(scoreOverall) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) 
               FROM ratings 
               WHERE gameID = '$id';
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: Returns the error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in on line 77". On line 77 I am echoing $id which echos before I tried this SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Hope it is your helpful

```
$sqlOverall="SELECT CAST(AVG(scoreOverall) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) FROM ratings WHERE gameID=$id";
$scoreOverall = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlOverall);
foreach ($scoreOverall as $value) { 
    $scoreOverall = $value['CAST(AVG(queue_status) AS DECIMAL(10,1))']; 
    echo $scoreOverall;
}
```